# When bitwise and & operation is greater or equal to bitwise xor ^ operation?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bitwise-xor

When bitwise & operation is greater or equal to bitwise ^ operation?

For example, 4&7 >= 4^7 is true.

How do we know when it will be true?

The one way is to do manually what will be hidden trick?

Comment: Is there any reason/context for asking?

Comment: That is a part of my project by which I am trying to create some random secret codes for my project so trying to optimize it.

Comment: Make a black-and-white image with 1024 x 1024 pixels using the truth values of `x & y >= x ^ y`. What do you see?

Comment: for `i&j >= i^j` where i and j are random numbers between 1 and 100, it returns true about 25% of the time

Comment: Nice idea man i got it !!

Comment: The pattern is actually kind of neat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we just talk about the set bits. This condition will be true when the highest *common* set bit is also the highest set bit in each of the numbers.

Why? Because when the highest set bit in both numbers is also a common bit, then that bit will be set in the result of the AND operation. And it will not be set in the result of the XOR operation.

And if the highest set bit in the largest number is not also set in the lower number, then necessarily that bit will be set in the XOR operation and not set in the AND operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a quick `String` image like so:

```swift
for i in 1...25 {
    var foo = ""
    for j in 1...25 {
        foo += i&j >= i^j ? "•" : " "
    }
    print(foo)
}
```

```
•                        
 ••                      
 ••                      
   ••••                  
   ••••                  
   ••••                  
   ••••                  
       ••••••••          
       ••••••••          
       ••••••••          
       ••••••••          
       ••••••••          
       ••••••••          
       ••••••••          
       ••••••••          
               ••••••••••
               ••••••••••
               ••••••••••
               ••••••••••
               ••••••••••
               ••••••••••
               ••••••••••
               ••••••••••
               ••••••••••
               ••••••••••
```

Notice how the squares are growing quadratically.

From this you can see that when `i == j == true` it always returns true.